# Neo4j Lucene index - perform fuzzy search with wildcards

Tags: java, search, autocomplete, lucene, neo4j

I am trying to setup an autosuggest/autocomplete search functionality using Neo4J's Lucene full-text indexes. I want my search to have fuzziness. 
Here is my code.

```
 Index<Node> ind = db.index().forNodes("node_auto_index",
     MapUtil.stringMap( IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type", "fulltext" )) ;
 for ( Node node : ind.query("name:" + searchTerm.replace(" ", "?") + "~")) {
     ...
 }
```

The problem arises when there is a space character in searchTerm. Lucene treats the space as the start of next field and throws an error. I figured out that space character can be replaced using ? wildcard. But if I do that I dont get any matches from lucene. What is the work around this issue ?

Also I would like to know if its possible to combine * & ~ since I want the results to start  with the words being type while ~ operator looks for occurrence of the term anywhere in the string

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you encapsulate your search term in double quotes. This is a requirement of lucene for n-grams. It's because their syntax has reserved keywords that use spaces.

```
Index<Node> ind = db.index().forNodes("node_auto_index",
    MapUtil.stringMap( IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type", "fulltext" )) ;
for ( Node node : ind.query("name:" + ("\"" + searchTerm + "\"") + "~")) {
    ...
}
```

See

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity%20Searches

Comment: Then there are a few options. I would recommend not using Neo4j for autocomplete. Rather you should create a JSON map using a file storage format you're familiar with. See my example on building predictive autocomplete with Neo4j -- https://github.com/kbastani/predictive-autocomplete